# How to add posts with thumbnails to my dropdown menu?

Tags: menus, post-thumbnails, dropdown

I want to create the same effect in [Listverse](http://listverse.com/) menu. I have a dropdown menu, and I want to add a post section with thumbnail, as shown in the image below. How to achieve that? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to install a mega-menu plugin see on codecanyon
2. u can try it with css html php sample [Mega Menu Jquery](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/)
3. you can show post on screen in Screen option in menu [image]